# Stay in Annotation mode in Okular?

Tags: pdf, tablet, okular, bamboo, annotation

I am trying to markup a PDF that I have in Okular. I would like to make a lot of notes with my Bamboo tablet, but every time I lift the pen, I go back to the default mode. This obviously defeats the purpose.

Is there a way to stay in Annotation mode across strokes? Or is there another tool in Ubuntu that will do what I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With a single left mouse button click on an annotation tool button you can use a tool once. If you e.g. want to highlight all important parts of a text, you can activate that tool permanently by double clicking on the tool button. Press the Esc key or click the tool button again to leave the permanent mode.

Comment: Thanks! Was that in the documentation somewhere? I couldn't find it.

Comment: No problem, right there: https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html

Comment: don't feel bad, I had the same exact experience!

Comment: yep there is no indication in the UI that the annotation mode is temporary or permanent...quite unintuitive and should be fixed!

Comment: It seems that the double-click stopped working with the new version (using now 20.12.3)?. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is now a *Keep active* button in the annotation toolbar. You can enable the annotation toolbar after using <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. Then <kbd>right-click</kbd> in the area that pops up and enable the annotation toolbar. For me the annotation toolbar was already there, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Location of Spin button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdDrn.png)

In v23.04.3 (Windows) or maybe in the older versions, there is an **Spin button** at the final right of the Annotation Toolbar for keeping the annotation tool active after use.